# Set EmailMessage Visibility

Tags: emailmessage

I have two users who share the same profile and have access to Cases.

When one user sends an Email to the Case's Contact from the "Activity Composer" an `EmailMessage` appears in the `Email` related list for this Case.

However, when another user visits the Case record, there is no Email in the related list.

As EmailMessage has no visibility settings in the profile, I would assume it's visibility is controlled by its parent, or in this instance, a Case.

Both users share the same profile, and I have set "View All Data" on the Case object for this profile.

Comment: What's the sharing settings for the EmailMessage object in your org? I suspect the OWD for EmailMessage is set to private, and there is no sharing rules in place to extend sharing access to the EmailMessage record.

Comment: @JasonFung that's a good idea - under `Sharing Settings` I see: `Contact Point Email`, `List Email`, `Email Linkage`, `Email Send` and `Individual Email Result`, all except `Contact Point Email` are Public Read/Write or Public Read Only? Which would affect EmailMessage?

Comment: @jordan.baucke Did you got any solution for this use case?